# Why border was not showing for dynamic table

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-apps-script

Creating a web App using Google Apps script.

I was retrieving data from the spreadsheet and trying to display in a table format.

Everything is working fine except Border for table..,

Below is the code .

```
 <html>

  <body>

<table border="1">
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

   window.onload = function()
   {
       google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getpres();
    }


 function showData(data)
 {
  var html = "";
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) 
  { 
    if(data[i][0] <= 2)
    {


  document.write("<tr><td>Number " + i + " is:</td>");
  document.write("<td>" + data[i][3] + "</td></tr>");

    }
  }

}
    </script>
    </table>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: From the [W3C documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_table_border.asp): _"The border attribute of <table> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."_

Comment: I have tried CSS too as per the documentation , It was not working !! Border was working for some other code.. It wasn't working particularly for this code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add border - better to use css inside style tag, I've added that for you

And, as far as I know, it's not okay to put script tag inside table.
Better put script tag next to table tag, and the last thing - you did document.write, that mean's browsers had to update page layout after every insert, better to join all rows to one string and add it only once.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id="table" class="table"></table>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getpres();
            }
            function showData(data) {
                var rows = [];
                for (var i = 0, ii = data.length; i < ii; i++) {
                    if(data[i][0] <= 2) {
                        rows.push('<tr>');
                        rows.push('<td>Number ' + i + ' is:</td>')
                        rows.push('<td>' + data[i][3] + '</td>');
                        rows.push('</tr>');
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = rows.join('');
            }
        </script>
        <style>
            .table{
                border: 1px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To get a border around every cell, do `td{ border: 1px solid black; }`

Comment: I have added border attribute for the above code.. Now, It was working fine !! Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me, add a width attribute also to see if that helps if not just style it with css `border:1px solid #ccc;`